# Just a simple thing about windowsTitle change background in Java

Tags: java, android

i wan't to do a simple thing, my background's windowTitle must change in my application. But how i can access to my background's windowTitle ?

My style.xml :

```
<resources>
<style name="CustomWindowTitleBackground">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/fond</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">40dip</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBackground</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

And in my Activity :

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.page_doc);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);
```

How i can do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the ids of the window_title layout. Just like you would do with normal layout.
I assume that you have something like a LinearLayout in your window_title layout. Just use the id of it to get it and set the background Drawable.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this

```
((TextView)((FrameLayout)((LinearLayout)((ViewGroup) activity.getWindow().getDecorView()).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back);
```

Comment: I tried this :

     RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutWindowTitle);
        rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fond_doc);